# shell_exec not working in php web appl

Tags: bash, shell, php

I made a shell script that detects network interfagces then for each interface it detects the IP address, mask, broadcast address, then it makes a ping to all IP addresses for this network interface.

The script has execute permissions. Normally, the script will save the list of network interfaces (eth0 eth1 wlan0) in a file called "resultat" but when I run this script from a web page with php's `shell_exec` command (`echo 'password for www-data user' | / usr/lib/cgi-bin/sudo -S global.sh bin/bash/"`) no output is generated.

If I run the same script as user `www-data` in the terminal, the result file is correctly populated.

The script:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #####   paramères relatives au connexion à la base de données
  HOST_BDD="localhost"
  LOGIN="root"
  PASSWD="password"
  NOM_BDD="dbnessus"
  ##### ces requettes pour vider les tables avant de faire la detection
  vider2="TRUNCATE machine_connecte"
  echo $vider2 | /usr/bin/mysql -h $HOST_BDD 
  -u $LOGIN -p$PASSWD -s $NOM_BDD

  vider1="TRUNCATE interfaces"
  echo $vider1 | /usr/bin/mysql -h $HOST_BDD 
  -u $LOGIN -p$PASSWD -s $NOM_BDD

  initialise="ALTER TABLE machine_connecte AUTO_INCREMENT=0"
  echo $initialise | /usr/bin/mysql -h $HOST_BDD 
  -u $LOGIN -p$PASSWD -s $NOM_BDD
  #######################################################

  /usr/lib/cgi-bin/get_interface.sh > /usr/lib/cgi-bin/liste_interfaces
  while read line; 
  do 

  ip=$(/usr/lib/cgi-bin/get_ip.sh $line)
  mask=$(/usr/lib/cgi-bin/get_netmask.sh $line)
  bcast=$(/usr/lib/cgi-bin/get_bcast.sh $line)


  ###fonction is_alive_ping
  is_alive_ping()
  {
    ping -i 100 -c 1 $1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
   [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo  $i >>/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resultat
  }
  cat /dev/null >/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resultat;
  #########


  ###division des octet d'adresse de broadcst
  if [ "$ip" != "" ]
  then
  i1="$(echo $bcast |cut -d"." -f1)"
  i2="$(echo $bcast |cut -d"." -f2)"
  i3="$(echo $bcast |cut -d"." -f3)"
  i4="$(echo $bcast |cut -d"." -f4)"
  fi
  ###  { HostID / NetworkID } / classe du réseau

  ##################### A.255.255.255 Classe A
  if [ "$i2" == "255" ]
  then
for i in "$i1".{1..254}.{1..254}.{1..254}
do
is_alive_ping $i & disown
done
  fi
  ##################### A.B.255.255 Classe B
  if [ "$i2" != "255" ] && [ "$i3" == "255" ]
  then
for i in "$i1.$i2".{1..254}.{1..254} 
do
is_alive_ping $i & disown
done
  fi
  ##################### A.B.C.255 Classe C
  if [ "$i2" != "255" ] && [ "$i3" != "255" ]&& [ "$i4" == "255" ]
  then
for i in "$i1.$i2.$i3".{1..254} 
do
is_alive_ping $i & disown
    done
  fi
  ################
while read ip_up; 
do 
hostname=$(/usr/bin/resolveip -s $ip_up 2>/dev/null)
if [ "$hostname" == "" ]
then
hostname="*"
fi
mac=$(/usr/sbin/arp -a $ip_up |cut -d" " -f4)
if [ "$ip_up" == "$ip" ] 
then
mac=$(/sbin/ifconfig $line |grep 'HWaddr'|grep -v '127.0.0.1'|awk '{ print $5}')
fi
OS=$( /usr/bin/nmap -A $ip_up |grep "Service Info:" |awk '{print $4,$5}' )
if [ "$OS" == "Unix, Linux" ] || [ "$OS" == "Linux" ]
then
OS="Linux"
elif [ "$OS" == "Windows " ]
then 
OS="Windows"
else
OS="*"
fi
 #sql1="INSERT INTO  dbnessus.interfaces (nom_interface)VALUES ('$line');"
 sql1="INSERT IGNORE INTO  dbnessus.interfaces (nom_interface)VALUES ('$line');"
 sql2="INSERT INTO  dbnessus.machine_connecte (idmachine ,ip_mach ,mask_mach,
 nom_mach,mac_mach ,os_mach ,interfaces_nom_interface)VALUES ( NULL,  '$ip_up',
 '$mask', '$hostname', '$mac',  '$OS',  '$line');"


 echo $sql1 | /usr/bin/mysql -h $HOST_BDD -u $LOGIN -p$PASSWD -s $NOM_BDD
 echo $sql2 | /usr/bin/mysql -h $HOST_BDD -u $LOGIN -p$PASSWD -s $NOM_BDD




    done < /usr/lib/cgi-bin/resultat
  ip=""
  done < /usr/lib/cgi-bin/liste_interfaces
  echo "cbon"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but what do you expect from `cat /dev/null >/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resultat;`? That will clear the file you have created.

Comment: yes every turn of the while loop (each detection of a network interface)) will erase the result of which contained contients the IP addresses connected with previous network interface file.
then it will make a new search (ping) and stores the address in the file "resultat$

Comment: when I run the script from the terminal it works but from a web page with php shell_exec () command is what's wrong

Comment: You say the script works when you run it as user `www-data` in terminal, but have you tried typing `echo 'password for www-data user' | / usr/lib/cgi-bin/sudo -S global.sh bin/bash/"`?  I see multiple issues: (1) space between `/` and `usr`; (2) doesn’t specify what user (`www-data`) it’s supposed to `sudo` to; (3) missing `/` before `bin/bash`; (4) unbalanced quote (`"`) character; and (5) I don’t know whether `sudo` will read a password from a pipe.  You may need to use an option like `-P`.  Also, (6) there shouldn’t be a `/` after `bash`, but it might not hurt.

Comment: good,(1) the / is indicated in the original file just a mistake when copying.(2) I have a password length 8 character I typed instead of this indication, but this is just for security resonant I chage here. I tried the same command that uses the shell script.
I logged into the terminal as user www-data, and then I tried typing:
###shell_exec("echo 'password' | sudo-S /bin/bash/usr/lib/cgi-bin/global.sh");
and it works but not from the php page

Comment: Is your PHP running in safe mode? As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php, `shell_exec` does not work in safe mode. Recall that the CLI and web configurations for PHP are normally different.

Comment: @tmedtcom: Does the `'password'` contains unescaped characters? Have you tried `escapeshellarg()` / `escapeshellcmd()`? Running in safe_mode?

Comment: in my php.ini the safe mode is set OFF.

Comment: i try to chande the password to just 4 characters, and still it is the same result

Answer (score 1):

Several ideas:

1. Check if `shell_exec` is in `php.ini`'s `disabled_functions`
   (php.ini: disabled_functions)
2. make sure PHP is not running in safe mode
   (php.ini: `safe_mode`)
3. make sure php-fpm process (if using php-fpm) or https (if using apxs) works under sufficient privilege (to run the shell script and execute these commands in script)
   (in this case you can su to that user and see if you can run it from bash)

Sorry I am unable to think of more so far...