# shell_exec with MySQL not working even though safe mode is off

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of script which working in terminal but does not work when I use it in PHP with [shell_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).I know a lot of questions similar to this question has been asked already but in my case the problem I am facing is that I have already tried the proposed solutions I found. Below is my simple code.

```
<?php

 $output = shell_exec('mysql -u root -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase< db.sql');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

So far this is [the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847575/shell-exec-not-working-in-php-web-appl) I have found.

Does anyone knows what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `db.sql` is in the correct directory? Try changing that to the absolute path to the file.

Comment: I have tried ./db.sql and absolute path like /var/www/myweb/db.sql , but the result is still the same. however all these work in terminal

Comment: It's probably the PATH problem that JakeGould's answer addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shell_exec` is this:

```
$output = shell_exec('mysql -u root -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase< db.sql');
```

And your command is this:

```
mysql -u root -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase< db.sql
```

The reason that command works when you are in the shell is the binary path to `mysql` is part of your user login profile.

To see what I mean, login to the shell as yourself and then type `echo $PATH` and what you will see is a list of search paths the shell uses to figure out where binaries you are attempting to run are located.

But when you attempt to run a script via `shell_exec()` the Apache server user running PHP is making the sell call. And that user typically does not have binary paths set. So you need to provide the full path to `mysql` which might be:

```
/usr/bin/mysql
```

Or:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

The best solution is from the shell use the `which` command like so:

```
which mysql
```

And then take the full path provided and adjust your `shell_exec()` command as follows; using `/usr/bin/` for example:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase < db.sql');
```

Also, where is `db.sql` actually located? You would have to prepend the full path to that MySQL script like this as well; using `/full/path/to/this/` for example:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 my database < /full/path/to/this/db.sql');
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. however I am still getting the same result. I have tried both alternatives with full path and without full path. and I still can't find out why it is not working

Comment: Thank you the command you proposed actually works. I made a syntax error when editing.